# h2o.init() error ports are not available in R

Tags: r, h2o

I just installed h2o (3.40.0.4) in R. I ran the following:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

and got back the following:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\some_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQLhwRy\file313c1b97627f/h2o_some_userdov_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\some_user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQLhwRy\file313c4c7f3347/h2o_some_userdov_started_from_r.err

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
java version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Diagnostic HTTP Request:
   HTTP Status Code: -1
HTTP Error Message: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
18:12:11.226 [main] WARN  hex.tree.xgboost.XGBoostExtension - Cannot initialize XGBoost backend! Xgboost (enabled GPUs) needs: 
  - CUDA 8.0
XGboost (minimal version) needs: 
  - GCC 4.7+
For more details, run in debug mode: `java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties -jar h2o.jar`

05-22 18:12:14.024 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: ----- H2O started  -----
05-22 18:12:14.026 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Build git branch: rel-zz_kurka
05-22 18:12:14.029 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Build git hash: 5ff8870f912c6110d7b6988f577c020de10496ec
05-22 18:12:14.031 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Build git describe: jenkins-3.40.0.3-122-g5ff8870
05-22 18:12:14.032 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Build project version: 3.40.0.4
05-22 18:12:14.033 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Build age: 24 days
05-22 18:12:14.034 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Built by: 'jenkins'
05-22 18:12:14.035 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Built on: '2023-04-28 12:08:23'
05-22 18:12:14.036 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Found H2O Core extensions: [KrbStandalone, Infogram]
05-22 18:12:14.037 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_some_userdov_swz423, -ip, localhost, -web_ip, localhost, -port, 54321, -ice_root, C:/Users/some_user~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQLhwRy, -nthreads, 6, -allow_unsupported_java]
05-22 18:12:14.038 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Java availableProcessors: 8
05-22 18:12:14.039 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Java heap totalMemory: 510.0 MB
05-22 18:12:14.040 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Java heap maxMemory: 7.96 GB
05-22 18:12:14.041 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Java version: Java 11.0.6 (from Sun Microsystems Inc.)
05-22 18:12:14.042 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: JVM launch parameters: [-Djava.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., -ea, -agentpath:C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cyjagent.dll]
05-22 18:12:14.043 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: JVM process id: 10320@5CG9061HY2
05-22 18:12:14.044 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: OS version: Windows 10 10.0 (amd64)
05-22 18:12:14.045 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Machine physical memory: 31.85 GB
05-22 18:12:14.046 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Machine locale: en_US
05-22 18:12:14.047 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1684797130431
05-22 18:12:14.047 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: User name: 'some_userdov'
05-22 18:12:14.048 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: IPv6 stack selected: false
05-22 18:12:14.049 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1), 127.0.0.1
05-22 18:12:14.050 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
05-22 18:12:14.051 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net0 (Microsoft 6to4 Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.052 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:ppp0 (WAN Miniport (PPPOE))
05-22 18:12:14.052 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth0 (WAN Miniport (IPv6))
05-22 18:12:14.053 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:ppp1 (RAS Async Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.055 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan0 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.057 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net1 (Microsoft IP-HTTPS Platform Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.058 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth1 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.059 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth2 (Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.060 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan1 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.061 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth3 (Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network))
05-22 18:12:14.061 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth4 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM), 192.168.0.116
05-22 18:12:14.062 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth4 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM), 2601:483:900:21f8:be28:2df4:49bb:2c7a
05-22 18:12:14.063 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth4 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM), 2601:483:900:21f8:7cbe:3d33:6313:e3a8
05-22 18:12:14.064 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth4 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM), fe80:0:0:0:9c65:405f:3791:3f1b%eth4
05-22 18:12:14.065 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net2 (WAN Miniport (L2TP))
05-22 18:12:14.066 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth5 (Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device)
05-22 18:12:14.066 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth6 (WAN Miniport (IP))
05-22 18:12:14.067 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth7 (Realtek USB GbE Family Controller)
05-22 18:12:14.068 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth8 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.069 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net3 (WAN Miniport (SSTP))
05-22 18:12:14.070 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net4 (Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.071 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth9 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3), 10.92.145.169
05-22 18:12:14.072 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth9 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3), fe80:0:0:0:c86a:aa5:322a:855d%eth9
05-22 18:12:14.073 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan2 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265)
05-22 18:12:14.074 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth10 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2)
05-22 18:12:14.075 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth11 (WAN Miniport (IP)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.075 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth12 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter), 192.168.56.1
05-22 18:12:14.076 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth12 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter), fe80:0:0:0:1cd4:83df:3d19:8a23%eth12
05-22 18:12:14.077 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net5 (WAN Miniport (IKEv2))
05-22 18:12:14.078 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth13 (Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64)
05-22 18:12:14.079 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:net6 (WAN Miniport (PPTP))
05-22 18:12:14.080 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth14 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.081 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan3 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2)
05-22 18:12:14.082 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth15 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor))
05-22 18:12:14.083 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth16 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.084 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth17 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.084 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth18 (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.085 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan4 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.086 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth19 (WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.087 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth20 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.115 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth21 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.116 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth22 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.117 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth23 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.118 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth24 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM-VirtualBox NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.119 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth25 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.120 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth26 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.121 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan5 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.122 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan6 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265-VirtualBox NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.122 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan7 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.123 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan8 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.124 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth27 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.125 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan9 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.125 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan10 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.126 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan11 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-VirtualBox NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.127 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan12 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.127 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan13 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.128 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth28 (Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter)
05-22 18:12:14.129 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth29 (Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter-Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.130 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth30 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.130 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth31 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter-VirtualBox NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.131 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth32 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.132 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth33 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.133 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth34 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter), 172.24.80.1
05-22 18:12:14.134 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Possible IP Address: eth34 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter), fe80:0:0:0:203e:c59a:d223:79c8%eth34
05-22 18:12:14.135 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth35 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.136 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth36 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3-VirtualBox NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.137 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth37 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.138 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:eth38 (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.139 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan14 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.140 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan15 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.140 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan16 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-VirtualBox NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.141 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan17 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.142 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main  INFO water.default: Network interface is down: name:wlan18 (Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000)
05-22 18:12:14.143 127.0.0.1:54321       10320        main FATAL water.default: On localhost/127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again. 
Error Output:
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
```

I apologize for this extra long error message, but how can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Do you get output from the terminal command `telnet localhost 54321`? Also, it is probably worth asking for help on the h2O gitter: https://app.gitter.im/#/room/%23h2oai_h2o-3:gitter.im

Comment: Have you disabled your antivirus software?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like some kind of a firewall is blocking the ports, I would suggest to investigate that